# The model backing the 'ApplicationDbContext' context has changed since the database was created When upload project to server

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

why i find this error:

```
The model backing the 'ApplicationDbContext' context has changed since the database was created. This could have happened because the model used by ASP.NET Identity Framework has changed or the model being used in your application has changed. To resolve this issue, you need to update your database. Consider using Code First Migrations to update the database (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301867).  Before you update your database using Code First Migrations, please disable the schema consistency check for ASP.NET Identity by setting throwIfV1Schema = false in the constructor of your ApplicationDbContext in your application.
public ApplicationDbContext() : base("ApplicationServices", throwIfV1Schema:false)
```

this error happens when i upload project to the server also it working good in local.
my application context code is:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
   public ApplicationDbContext()
            : base("DefaultConnection",throwIfV1Schema : false)
   {
   }
}
```

Knowing i'm add this code in AppStart{}

```
Database.SetInitializer<ApplicationDbContext>(null);
```

Comment: If you're not using an initializer or code first migrations, then make sure your model classes match your database.

Comment: look again carefully, for some reason the framework thinks otherwise

Comment: Just an idea, but if you can't see any differences in the c# code, then maybe temporarily use a `CreateDatabaseIfNotExists` initializer and run the code on a new different local database. Then compare that generated database with your database to see if they really are the same.

Comment: Even if the classes are all the same, the model itself could be different between your local and server databases. Compare the most recent record in the `dbo.EdmMetadata` table between your local and server and see if they are the same. If not, then EF is telling you that the model is different (even if the classes are not).